# How to update or overwrite global variable value to be use in differents scripts? Jquery

Tags: jquery

So I have this function that is changing the css and trying to catch the new value of the template inside a globalVariable, the point is I want to use this variable in another script.

My scrip-one.js

```
var templateModeTypography = 'black';

$('.a-t-img').on('click', function () {
  $(this).find('.toggle-wrapper').toggleClass('is-active');
  $(':root').toggleClass('dark');
  templateModeTypography == 'black' ? templateModeTypography = 'white' : templateModeTypography = 'black';
  console.log(templateModeTypography);
});
```

So when console.log inside the function I see the values changing on toogle , but if I console log outside the function the variable is not being updated, not too familiar with Jquery, so not sure if this is the normal behavior.

so in my second script which is in a different file I have something like

my-script-two.js

```
Chart.defaults.font.size = 16;
Chart.defaults.color = 'black';
Chart.defaults.borderColor = 'transparent';
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.backgroundColor = 'black';
Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.position = 'bottom';
```

So where I have the value 'black' I want to use my variable instead. So by example:

```
Chart.defaults.color = templateModeTypography;
```

So when I console log from this other file, I see have access to the variable, but the result is always 'black' because is never target. Now the other question is is possible to call that function value to the use instead?

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When do you use this value in the second script?  Before or after invoking the click event which changes it?  The described behavior implies that you're using it before it's been changed.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for reading, so I have at the end of the body tag: <sript src="jquery.min.js" ..> then <script src="script-one.js"...> and finally <script src="script-two.js"...> where script one is the one with the event on click

Comment: Ok, but in `script-two.js` when do you use this value?  For example, if this value is used immediately upon loading the page, then clearly it won't be whatever the code changes it to when the user clicks something after the page is loaded.

Comment: the script-two is being execute on load page, is not wrapped inside a function or so. Not sure if that's the issue, I also when console log inside the same script file and outside the function the value is always 'black' :-/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the logic of what ths code is doing.  When the page loads, the value of the variable is explicitly set to `'black'`:

```
var templateModeTypography = 'black';
```

When is the value changed?  It's changed at some later time in response to a user interaction, specifically when the user clicks on an element somewhere on the page:

```
$('.a-t-img').on('click', function () {
```

So, if you're *using* the value immediately upon loading the page then it's certainly not going to be whatever you change it to *in the future* when the user clicks on that element.

Basically, you can't use a value *before you've set it*.

Whatever `Chart` is, you'd want to perform this operation *after* the user clicks that element (so in the click handler function you've defined):

```
Chart.defaults.color = templateModeTypography;
```

I don't know if that exact line of code will produce the desired result of course, because I don't know what `Chart` is or how to use it.  If it's some 3rd party library that you're configuring/initializing then your options include:

1. Consult the library's API documentation for how to change that setting after initialization.
2. Re-initialize the library/component/etc. after the user clicks the element.
3. Don't initialize the library/component/etc. until after the user clicks the element.

But any way you approach it, the underlying issue is the same.  If you want to use a value that's provided by the user clicking on something then you have to wait until the user clicks on something in order to use it.